# How to work with database and UI under threads?

Tags: database, multithreading, delphi, user-interface, responsive-design

I am interested in make better programs with more responsive design and capabilities. Nowadays, when I create my programs that access data remotely, my interface freezes and there is no animated GIF to work on that condition.

I was told by David Hefferman that animated GIF that are created in the VCL do not respond even in threads because the VCL is in the main thread, and the same goes to databases.

My doubt here is how to work with threads, specifically in databases, so I have lots of questions about it.

Do I have to implement my entire database in thread functions and procedures?
If that is correct, then I can't use database by dropping components to the Form, right? 
But what about the user input and grids? Will they work correctly with those threads or will I have to user regular `TEdit` instead of `TDBEdit` to then send it's content to a insert/update sql command?

The main objective in here is to create Delphi application that access remote databases like MySQL using Zeos but not freezing for every drop of consult made in the server. At least the smaller ones. It would be very ugly if the system were to download a list of records to a table and the user could still input things. For those cases I would like very much that my animated GIF (or other solutions) could work.

*Thank you for any help at all!*

Comment: IMHO, the question is to wide-ranging to be answered here.

Comment: Is there anything else for the user to do while waiting for the database to respond?

Comment: Yes, not freak out because the application screen went gray and there is a "(not responding)" message at the title...

Comment: In a multitask world, a real multitask application could make the difference in time saving at a company, for example, the attendant could register the client, and while it goes to the database, the attendant could start browsing the product list that client is buying. @MarcusAdams

Comment: I suggest you read the excellent 'Multithreading The Delphi Way' tutorial by Martin Harvey. It can be found online at several places or downloaded from Embarcadero at http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/14809. This will give you a thorough understanding of what treading is and can/can't do, so that you get more general insight for your questions "do I have to implement X in threads", as well as how to approach that practically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the best approach is to drop your database components on a Data module and then create this data module dynamically in each thread. Database components typically work fine if they are created and initialized in the thread that is using them.

There are, however, caveats - if you are connecting to a Firebird database, you should make sure that only one thread at the time is establishing a connection. (Use a critical section around the code that connects to the database.) This holds for Firebird 1.5, 2.0 and 2.1 but may not be necessary anymore for Firebird 2.5 (I didn't yet have opportunity to test it).

EDIT (in answer to EASI's comment): Yes, connecting to a database can take some time. If you frequently need to execute short operations, it is best to keep threads connected and running for a longer period of time.

I can think of two ways to do that. 1) Keep threads alive and connected and run a message loop inside. This loop would receive commands from the main thread, process them and return a result. 2) Keep threads initialized and connected in a thread pool and activate them when you need to perform a database operation.

Basically, both approaches are the same, the difference is in the level which handles 'receive and process command' loop.

The second approach can be easily implemented in the [OmniThreadLibrary](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com) by using the `IOmniConnectionPool.SetThreadDataFactory` mechanism. See [Adding connection pool mechanism to OmniThreadLibrary](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/02/adding-connection-pool-mechanism-to.html) and demo [24_ConnectionPool](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2F24_ConnectionPool) for more information. Alternatively, you can use the high-level abstraction [Background worker](http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book%3ahighlevel%3abackgroundworker) where you can establish database connection on a per-thread basis in a [Task initialization](http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book%3ahighlevel%3abackgroundworker#task_initialization) block.

Comment: My preoccupation about this is if could it take to much more time to reach the database and start the basics like connecting to the database server each time we need to use it. I think it is a very good approach to use with random short consults, but is it ok to use when the data form is to be open for a long time while the user puts data and make "ajax like" requests?

Comment: RemObjects DataAbstract implements just such a connection pool and has a pretty good multi-threading system built in.